# Java Regex - reduce spaces in a string

Tags: java, regex

I don't have time to get my head around regex and I need a quick answer.  Platform is Java.

I need the string

```
"Some text   with  spaces"
```

...to be converted to

```
"Some text with spaces"
```

i.e., 2 or more consecutive spaces to be changed to 1 space.

Comment: Do you mean ONLY spaces, or do you mean "any run of consecutive whitespace characters" (which could include tabs, etc.)?

Answer (score 47):

```
String a = "Some    text  with   spaces";
String b = a.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
assert b.equals("Some text with spaces");
```

Comment: This will make replacements of all single spaces with a single space, not very efficient.  You should only replace if there are two or more consecutively.

Comment: @Chris - don't start optimizing the regex prematurely, I believe this will suffice.

Comment: Yes, this solution is not as efficient as it could be, but that would only matter if this operation were taking place inside a performance hotspot.  It's definitely not worth a downvote.

Comment: There's nothing optimized about not replacing single spaces with single spaces.  This *guarantees* a string replacement for every word boundary in your string.

Comment: It's a valid point, and I would always use \s{2,} or equivalent in this situation, but practically speaking, it's just not that important.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this is optimized by the libraries already to only do replacements on multiple spaces. This is readable and gets the job done.

Answer (score 12):

If we're talking specifically about spaces, you want to be testing specifically for spaces:

```
MyString = MyString.replaceAll(" +", " ");
```

Using **`\s`** will result in **all whitespace** being replaced - sometimes desired, othertimes not.

Also, a simpler way to only match 2 or more is:

```
MyString = MyString.replaceAll(" {2,}", " ");
```

(Of course, both of these examples can use `\s` if any whitespace is desired to be replaced with a single space.)

Comment: It worth remembering that you need something like myString = myString.replaceAll(" +", " "); otherwise it won't do anything useful.

Comment: Indeed - I think I simply copied the format of a (now deleted) answer, but will correct it.

Answer (score 1):

For Java (not javascript, not php, not anyother):

```
txt.replaceAll("\\p{javaSpaceChar}{2,}"," ")
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a constant of [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for avoid recompiled the expression every time:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile(" {2,}");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Some text   with spaces";
    System.out.println(
        REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input).replaceFirst(" ")
    );  // prints "Some text with spaces"
}
```

In another way, the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) include in the class [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) the method [`normalizeSpace`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#normalizeSpace%28java.lang.String%29).