# replace multiple whitespaces between words with single blank

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace multiple whitespaces between words in a line with a single blank using java.I used the below code to do this. But it does not work when one of the words in the two words is a hyphen '-'. Can you please let me know how to replace multiple whitespaces between words in a line with a single blank if one of those word is a hyphen '-'.

```
String s="1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1     2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2"

s.replaceAll("\\b\\s{2,}\\b", " ");
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a better example of what doesn't work please?

Comment: If i have a line with 5 words i want to ensure that multiple whitespace between any two consecutive words in the line is reduced to  a single blank. But the above code does not work if one word among the two consecutive words in the line is a hyphen '-'. Can u tell me how to achieve this in java

Comment: Refer to the post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575500/java-regex-reduce-spaces-in-a-string

Comment: Hyphen is not part of a word boundary. Is the word boundary important to you or could you just do s.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " "); ?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use:

```
String s = "1   -   2   2"
s.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");
```

gives: "1 - 2 2"

or even more simply:

```
s.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

Comment: See [OMG Ponies](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx) "zero-width non-joiner". Also check http://ideone.com/bps9d

Comment: s.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ") worked well for me. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the word boundary `\\b` because there're no ones between a dash `-` and a space.