# Removing spaces in a string if more than two spaces continuously exists

Tags: regex, string

Lets say I have string like this,

```
String sample = "This is a sample  string    with more than   two spaces in      a string   ";
```

Now what I have to do to make the string to have only one space between each word.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Regex - reduce spaces in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575500/java-regex-reduce-spaces-in-a-string)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If literally mean "space" then you can replace `/ {2,}/` with a single space. Note that a space in the regular expression matches a space in the text.

If by "space" you actually mean "all whitespace" (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.), then use `\s+` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Match them with `\s+` regex and replace with single space.. 
If you only want to replace multiple spaces (not tabs and other white chars) use `\ +`

Answer (score 1):

If this is C#, then you can do

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
…
      String sample = "This is a sample  string    with more than   two spaces in      a string   ";
      sample = Regex.Replace(sample, @"\s+", " ");
```